# Changing the Name of a SPFolder

Tags: document-library, folder

I am trying to update the name of a folder with the code below:

```
folder.Item[SPBuiltInFieldId.Title] = "New folder name";
folder.Item.SystemUpdate();
```

I can see that the Title field of the item associated with the folder is changed. But on the default view of the document library, under the Name column I still see the old folder name.

What is the proven way of changing a folder name in SharePoint?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update the Name field instead of the Title field.

```
folder.Item[SPBuiltInFieldId.Name] = "New folder name";
folder.Item.SystemUpdate();
```

Comment: Name field is read-only.

Comment: What happens if you try to do it like this: 'folder.Item["Name"] = "New folder name";'

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the Name property of the SPFolder object.

Comment: It is read-only and cannot be updated.

Comment: See the code posted by user above. That should work...l

Answer (score 0):

Old topic but the correct approach is to update Title and FileLeafRef properties.